# Best Practice for visualizing a Dictionary of Files with File Paths in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, listview, treeview

I have a Dictionary of 2 strings in C# which represents the Filename and the Path of the File. I want to visualize these into a Form with TreeView for the Folders and a ListView for the associated files for the actual folder. So this should present the data from a dictionary like to following as a file browser:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("File1","Folder1\\Folder2");
dict.Add("File2","Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3");
dict.Add("File3","Folder1");
dict.Add("File4","Folder1\\Folder2");
```

....

Im looking for a good Implementation to present this to a form:

```
public MethodBrowserForm(Dictionary<string, string> filesAndFolders)
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        string lastMethodFolder = "";

        Dictionary<int, List<string>> folderDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();


        foreach (var method in filesAndFolders)
        {

            // Compare Key Values for Folders

            if (!lastMethodFolder.Equals(method.Value))
            {

                // Extract Folder
                string[] directories = filesAndFolders.Value.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

                if (directories.Length > 1 )
                    // First Level Folders


                {
                   // Implementation for Visualization
                }


            }



            lastMethodFolder = filesAndFolders.Value;


        }   

    }
```

Comment: Your dictionary is basically backwards at best, your optimal solve would be dictionary of path segment (string) and value of class of a list of files and dictionary of path segments and value of said class... Then go through and break each path up in to segments and starting to add each node, which will naturally equate to a tree node regime of a tree view

Comment: Hi selbolder, I believe the UI component you are looking for is the "treeview"..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-an-explorer-style-interface-with-the-listview-and-treeview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication62
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("File1", "Folder1\\Folder2");
            dict.Add("File2", "Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3");
            dict.Add("File3", "Folder1");
            dict.Add("File4", "Folder1\\Folder2");

            List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> files = dict.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(x.Key, x.Value.Split(new char[] {'\\'}).ToList())).ToList();
            TreeNode root = new TreeNode();

            CreateTree(null, files);
            treeView1.ExpandAll();


        }

        public void CreateTree(TreeNode node, List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> files)
        {
            var folders = files.GroupBy(x => x.Value.First()).ToList();
            foreach (var folder in folders)
            {
                TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(folder.Key);
                if (node == null)
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                }
                else
                {
                    node.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                }
                List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> child = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> file in folder)
                {
                    if (file.Value.Count == 1)
                    {
                        newNode.Nodes.Add(file.Key);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> newFile = new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(file.Key, file.Value.Skip(1).ToList());
                        child.Add(newFile);
                    }
                }
                if (child != null)
                {
                    CreateTree(newNode, child);
                }
            }
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you that worked! Would you have an idea to split Folders and Files like in a file browser. Folders in the TreeView and the Files from that Folder in a ListView?

Comment: I did similar project a few days ago where I had just the full path including filename.  It was easier than above code just having the full path.  See codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/548924/Custom-Treeview